# How to use dplyr verbs rename and mutate in a same chunk

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to first rename my `x` variable to `newX` and then mutate a new column name `z` based on values of `newX` and `y`. Putting rename and mutate in same chunk result in an error.
Is there a way to use option 1 without an error?

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(
  x = sample(c(0,1), size = 5, replace = TRUE),
  y = sample(c(0,1), size = 5, replace = TRUE)
)
 # option 1
dat %>%
  rename(newX = x) %>%
  mutate(z = rowSums(dat[c("newX", "y")] == 1))

 # option 2
dat <- dat %>%
  rename(newX = x)
dat %>% 
  mutate(z = rowSums(dat[c("newX", "y")] == 1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dplyr::pick()`, which lets you “pick” variables from the current dataframe environment, rather than  `dat[c("vars")]`, which references the `dat` object before any transformations.

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  rename(newX = x) %>%
  mutate(z = rowSums(pick(newX, y) == 1))
```

```
  newX y z
1    0 0 0
2    1 0 1
3    0 0 0
4    0 1 1
5    1 1 2
```

Comment: thanks but `z` should be returned as an integer not TRUE and FALSE.

Comment: @rez - shift the parenthesis back one part - `mutate(z = rowSums(pick(newX, y) == 1))`

Comment: @rez Ah, I misread your original code. I edited my answer in line with @thelatemail’s correction.